# I'm stuck at integrating an arc length over a circle + angle between curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $(\phi, \theta)$ be the usual spherical coordinates. And let $\gamma (t) = (\phi (t), \theta (t))$ be the curve given by

$$ \phi (t) = \ln\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{t}{2}\right)\right),$$ $$ \theta (t) = \frac{\pi}{2} - t.$$

$t \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

> a) Compute the arc length of $ \gamma (t). $
>
> b) Show that the curve  cuts each "parallel" in a constant angle, by computing $(\gamma (t))'$ and $\psi_{\phi}$
>
> c) Make a diagram of the curves

So the formula for arc length would be $$ \begin{equation}
\ell_\gamma = \int_0^1 \sqrt{ \left ( \frac{dr}{dt} \right )^2 +
  r^2\sin^2 \theta \left ( \frac{d \phi}{dt} \right)^2  + 
    r^2 \left ( \frac{d \theta}{dt} \right )^2} \, dt.
\end{equation}$$

In my case, as  $$\phi'(t) = \frac 1 {2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{t}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{t}{2}\right)}, $$  and $$ \theta ' (t) = -1 ,$$ then

\begin{align*}
\ell_\gamma &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{
  \sin^2 \theta \left ( \frac{d \phi}{dt} \right)^2  + 
    \left ( \frac{d \theta}{dt} \right )^2} \, dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \sqrt{ \sin^2 \theta \left (\frac 1 {2\cos(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{t}{2})\sin(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{t}{2})} \right)^2  + 1} \, dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \sqrt{
  \left(\frac{\sin \theta }{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{t}{2})\sin(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{t}{2})} \right)^2  + 
      1} \, dt.
\end{align*}

I am stuck here. Before I go further, would this integral be correct? That $\sin^2(\theta)$ confuses me maybe, I don't know if I should change the argument to something else.

For exercise b) Could someone verify this reasoning?

I want the angle between two curves on the sphere, which is defined as the angle between the tangent vectors of this curves at the point of intersection. So I want to find $\alpha$ such that $\alpha = cos^{-1}(\frac{<\beta '(t), \gamma ' (t)>}{||\beta '(t) || ||\gamma ' (t)||}) $, because that is what the angle between two vectors in a vector space is.
So if $\beta (t) = (t, \theta_0)$ is a curve that describes the parallel curve in a sphere, with $\theta_0$ constant, Its tangents are given by $(1, 0),$. I already have the derivatives of $\gamma$ so $$ \alpha = cos^{-1}(\frac{<\beta '(t), \gamma ' (t)>}{||\beta '(t) || ||\gamma ' (t)||}) = cos^{-1}(\frac{<(1, 0) \dot (\frac{1}{sin{\frac{\pi}{2}- t}}, -1)>}{(1) \sqrt{csc^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-t) + 1}})$$
$$ = cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{sin{\frac{\pi}{2}- t}}{ \sqrt{csc^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-t) + 1}})$$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\theta'(t)=-1$ And $\sin\theta=\sin(\pi/2-t)$

Comment: For b), Choose a new path $\beta(t)$: $\theta=\theta_0$ constant and $\phi=t$ and compute the dot product of its tangent with the tangent of $\gamma$

Comment: The double-angle formula for the sine says $2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha = \sin(2\alpha).$ An instance of that says $ 2\cos\left( \frac\pi4 - \frac t 2\right) \sin\left(\frac\pi4 - \frac t2\right) = \sin\left( \frac\pi2 - t\right). $ And then recall that $\sin\left( \frac\pi2 - t\right) = \cos t. \qquad$

Comment: These are rhumb lines or Loxodromes of constant $\alpha$.  Cylindrical coordinates derivation is much simpler. $ r = a \,sech( \theta \cot \alpha )\,, z = a \,tanh(  \theta  \cot \alpha )\,$

Comment: In the "usual spherical coordinates", either $\varphi$ is latitude (starting with $\varphi=0$ at the north pole and going to $\varphi=\pi$ at the south pole) and $\theta$ longitude, or vice-versa. Which of those two conventions did you intend?

Comment: @MichaelHardy  sorry, I just rechecked this, yes, by usual spherical coordinates I meant $0$ minor or equal than $\theta$ & minor or equal than $2\pi$ , $\phi$ starts in $- \pi/2$ from north pole, ends in the south pole at $\pi/2$, which is what you suggested

Comment: @RafaBudria I think, that $\frac{\pi}{2} - t$ is the angle Im supposed to find, depending on the chosen $t$, is this correct? ( I computed $<(1, 0), (\frac 1 {\sin\left( \frac\pi2 - t\right)}, -1>$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \sqrt{ \left(\frac{\sin \theta }{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac t 2) \sin(\frac \pi 4 - \frac t 2)} \right)^2 + 1} \, dt \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos t} \right)^2+1} \, dt = \int_0^1 \sqrt{ \left( \frac{\cos t}{\cos t} \right)^2 + 1} \, dt = \int_0^1 \sqrt 2 \, dt = \sqrt 2.
\end{align}
The first two equalities are trigonometric identities:
\begin{align}
& 2\cos\left( \frac \pi 4 - \frac t 2 \right) \sin \left( \frac \pi 4 - \frac t 2 \right) = \sin\left( \frac \pi 2 - t \right) = \cos t \\[10pt]
& 
\end{align}

Comment: thanks! I got the same result but did something a little different, which I will answer in the post just for fun

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \sqrt{ \left(\frac{\sin (\frac{\pi}{2} - t) }{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac t 2) \sin(\frac \pi 4 - \frac t 2)} \right)^2 + 1} \, dt \\[10pt]
\end{align}

As $$\sin^2(\frac \pi 4 - \frac t 2)cos^2(\frac \pi 4 - \frac t 2) = \frac{1 - \cos(\pi - 2t)}{8},$$ then

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \sqrt{ \left(\frac{2\sin^2 (\frac{\pi}{2} - t) }{1 -\cos(2(\frac{\pi}{2} -  t ))}\right) + 1} \, dt & = \int_0^1 \sqrt{ \left(\frac{2\sin^2 (\frac{\pi}{2} - t) }{1 -[\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{2} -  t )- \sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2} -  t ))]}\right) + 1} \, dt  \end{align}

\begin{align} = \int_0^1 \sqrt{ \left(\frac{2\sin^2 (\frac{\pi}{2} - t) }{2\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2} - t)}\right) + 1} \, dt  = \sqrt2 \\[10pt] 
\end{align}